# Resize Bootstrap Modals window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Looking for help with this bootstrap modal.

When you click on a package (the colored blocks), the modal opens full screen. I cant figure out how to make it open more in a window.

Not sure if this is a bootstrap or j query thing.

site: http://pegasusbus.com/ebrochure

Comment: please let me know any files or code snippets you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code, preferably in the form of a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.portfolio-modal .modal-content {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!